# assistance with regex and multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, r, regex

I have a regex here. I'd like to know how to add multiple conditions, I have tried to use the pipe | but it does not seem to work as expected. I'm wanting to match files like:

Any assistance is appreciated.

```
file.jsx
mycool.file.jsx
mysupercoolfile.jsx
ignore /dist folder
```

I have tried to use the following regexs

```
  /folder\/file\.jsx?$/

  (/folder\/file\.jsx?|mycool.file)$/
```

**Edit**

I want to match the files:

folder/filename.jsx

fodler/test.filename.jsx

With the common pattern to be **filename**

Comment: What's the logic here?  Do you have a set of patterns you are looking to cover by a regex, or do you really intend to list out a bunch of filenames in an alternation?

Comment: ok, I have edited it..

Comment: NO!!! Don't post this data as a comment, add it to your question above.

Comment: I have edited the question....

Comment: Does `filename.test.jsx` match?  What about extensions?  Do extensions matter?

Comment: i always like this website to get an idea of if and how my regex works and to create one: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to extract filename from file path.

```
(?m)[^/\\]+$
```

**For Javascript:**

```
/[^\/\\]+$/mg
```